# How to catch javascript errors using async.waterfall on express.js server

Tags: node.js, express, async.js

I have an express server, which uses a queue to process in a FIFO order. So when I receive a request, I push it to the queue and launch a function called notifyQueue which is protected by a variable called isRunning (boolean). I'm always returning a success to the caller, so the request may take some time to process in the queue.

The function notifyQueue uses many functions exported from other files (js), so I call them using a require in the beginning of my server.js

These functions are using async.js library, so I pass a callback from server.js to test.js, the function in test.js uses an async.waterfall with functions that may make api calls ( asynchronous treatment ).

The problem here, if a javascript error is made (JSON.parse of an undefined object for example), the whole server stops immediatly, because of this syntaxError.

So, how can I handle the javascript error and callback the error to server.js, so it can continue running without stopping.

Comment: I think ```async.waterfall``` catch error in its ```callback``` function.

Comment: async.waterfall only catch errors that you implement, like when you make callback('this is an error'), it will be catched after the async.waterfall call.
This is not the problem, my problem is, how to catch javascript errors like parsing an undefined object without using the traditional try/catch especially when I'm using asynchronous functions.

Comment: In that case, you need to use ```try``` and ```catch``` in every function in ```async.waterfall```

Comment: But adding try catch on thousands of lines isn't the best idea, especially when I have asynchronous functions. I have mad e a lot of searching about the subject, even async.js team said that there is no way to do this, the only solution is to add try/catch in every block that contains synchrone code. But I'm not ready to pass a week adding try/catch blocks.

Comment: So I think the best solution for this, is to stop requiring the functions in server.js and use child_process to launch external nodejs scripts, so if one made a javascript error, it will stop the script, so server.js can continue running without crashing.